# Por que funciona passar o endereço de uma variável inteira para scanf() ler uma string?

Tags: c, string, scanf

#### Problema

Estava fazendo um código que seria para ler uma *string* e depois um valor inteiro:

```
int dia, h, m, s;
char dp;            //Dois pontos.
scanf("Dia %d",&dia);   //Inicio do evento.
...
```

Eu pensei em criar uma string para que o usuário digitasse a palavra "Dia" e depois o valor. Mas vi um código com esse exemplo acima, a palavra Dia segue dentro do `scanf()` sem armazenar em uma *string*. Nesse caso, se digitarmos exatamente como está dentro do `scanf()` (se fosse "dia " ou "diA " não funcionaria, tem que ser exatamente igual ao que ta dentro do `scanf`), ou seja "Dia xx" (onde xx pode ser um valor inteiro qualquer) ele funciona, e sem precisar ler caracteres e armazenar numa variável, ou seja, não apontei minha informação para nenhum endereço a ser armazenado.

Fiquei curioso em saber por que e como isso acontece.

#### Dúvidas

Por que, sem armazenar numa variável e sem apontar para algum endereço, sem informar quase nada pro compilador que iria digitar uma *string*, o `scanf()` executou normalmente?

Como isso aconteceu? Essa *string* tem que ir para algum lugar, e como não especifiquei, pra onde ela foi? Qual o processo que o compilador faz com essa *string*?

Comment: Nunca ouviste falar do scanf num livro de C? Então não devia ser livro de C... Fora de brincadeiras, há montes te informação na web sobre isso, uma pequena pesquisa resolveria a tua questão

Comment: Pois é, eu pesquisei. Mas até o momento ninguém consegue explicar como isso funciona, por que ele aceita que eu digite um conjunto de caracteres sem armazenar em lugar algum. Pra onde esses caracteres vão, e quais os riscos de se usar isso em um código.

Comment: Talvez as pessoas não consigam explicar porque você não esteja explicando bem qual é a sua dúvida. Você consegue melhorar isto. Eu talvez até consiga responder se eu entender um pouco melhor onde você quer chegar. Mas já lhe adianto, está armazenando em algum lugar sim.

Comment: Transmitir um pensamento já formulado para outra pessoa é realmente complicado, vou tentar ser mais claro.

Utilizar o scanf("Dia %d",&dia); permite digitar a string "Dia " sem armazenar ela em uma variável. Minha dúvida é entender o motivo do scanf aceitar que eu faça isso e saber pra onde essa string foi. E também entender COMO esse processo acontece, tipo, como o compilador faz isso? ex: "ah, ele recebe os caracteres e faz assim e assado com eles". Claro que isso deve ter sua margem de risco e gostaria de saber também sobre ela, ou seja, quais os risco que tenho em usar isso.
Ficou melhor?

Comment: A pergunta e interessante e dentro de escopo do site, mas @FilipiMaciel se conseguir dar uma limpeza a pergunta e deixa la mais clara, tenho a certeza que gerações vindouras vão poder aprender com ela.

Comment: Farei isso. Obrigado pelo toque!

Comment: Verifica sempre o valor devolvido pelo `scanf()`. Esse valor indica se a leitura correu bem ou mal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí. Você nunca viu em livros por causa disto. Acho que falta você entender pelo menos dois conceitos em C. Não vou entrar em muitos detalhes.

## Ponteiros

Quando você escreve `&dia` é o mesmo que dizer "no endereço de". Isto é uma forma de usar ponteiro. O ponteiro é um indicador que você vai usar um endereço de memória. O `scanf()` espera como demais parâmetros depois do primeiro que é a formatação que você mande como argumentos endereços de memória. Por isso que você não pode mandar apenas `dia`. Se mandasse esta variável desta forma, estaria mandando para a função o valor dela e não é isso que você deveria fazer. Então aí você até fez certo, mandou o endereço onde `dia` está armazenada.

`dia` assim como `h`, `m` e `s` e `dp` estão armazenadas em algum lugar como você declarou antes. Provavelmente uma em seguida da outra. Embora isto seja dependente de implementação e plataforma, provavelmente estas variáveis estão reservando 4 *bytes* cada que é o tamanho mais comum para o tipo `int`. O tipo `char` provavelmente tem 1 *byte*. Então você reservou 17 *bytes* em sequência.

Como você mandou o endereço de `dia` para o `scanf()`, ele **vai armazenar** os caracteres lidos neste endereço que você passou. Os primeiros quatro caracteres ficarão na variável `dia`, os quatro seguintes na variável `h` e assim por diante. E se eu digitar mais que 17 caracteres? Veja abaixo.

E pode guardar caracteres em inteiros? Pode!

## [Comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101)

Você está se valendo de um conceito chamado comportamento indefinido muito usado por linguagens como o C onde é preciso dar flexibilidade, facilidade de adaptação a diversas plataformas e formas criativas de melhorar a performance. C é quase um *Assembly*. C permite acesso direto ao *hardware*. C não controla demais o que o programador está fazendo. C entende que o programador deve saber o que está fazendo mesmo que ele faça algo potencialmente perigoso.

Então você está armazenando caracteres onde deveria ter inteiros. Nenhum problema. Claro que no seu caso não é a intenção, mas funciona (sempre falo que funcionar é diferente de estar certo). Cada 4 caracteres formarão um inteiro. Um valor que provavelmente não tem significado para seu programa, mas funciona.

O problema é quando você passar dos 17 caracteres. Aí você estará armazenando dados em área de memória não reservada para variáveis. Sim, isto é possível em C, por isto C é uma linguagem tão legal e poderosa mas também tão perigosa. C permite escrever em qualquer área da memória da sua aplicação. E é aí que você **pode** causar sérios problemas para ela. Em alguns casos, por coincidência não vai causar. Só que programar não pode obter resultados por coincidência.

Você poderia ter causado um problema ainda maior. Poderia ter mandado o valor de `dia` como se ele fosse o ponteiro (não estou falando de mandar o endereço como você mandou, seria chamar `scanf("Dia %d", dia);`). E poderia "funcionar". Claro que você estaria tentando armazenar os dados lidos pelo `scanf()` em um endereço que você sequer sabe o valor. Sim, porque você não inicializou valores para as variáveis, então os valores dela são aqueles que já estavam na memória naquela posição.

A não ser que você saiba muito bem o que está fazendo, tenha um motivo muito forte, nunca se valha de comportamento indefinido em seus programas.

## Erro de formatação do `scanf()`

Não vou falar muito porque a resposta do Omni já deu os detalhes importantes disto. A *string* de formatação está errada. Você está especificando uma formato que não existe, que não é bem interpretado pelo `scanf()`. Aí é onde você acaba nem conseguindo fazer nada. Mas não tem porque o compilador dar algum erro, a falha ocorre em execução.

A responsabilidade não é do compilador neste caso. É do código interno do `scanf()`. Não se esqueça que o `scanf()` é uma função como outra qualquer. Algum programador a criou como você cria seus programas. Ela não tem nenhum privilégio no C, ela é apenas um programa que vai junto com o C para facilitar realizar algumas operações de forma padrão. Por sorte a função não deixa fazer o que bem entende e não deixa causar todo o desastre que citei acima. Mas também está longe de fazer o que você quer e ser algo útil.

## Conclusão

Então esse seu "funciona" é um bem "mais ou menos". Não dá um erro, mas funcionar mesmo, não funciona.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Agora minha pergunta foi respondida, obrigado cara.

Answer (score 4):

O que acontece neste caso é que esta a passar ao `scanf(...)` uma string de formatação. Esta string de formatação indica ao `scanf(...)` como processar o input lido, ou seja é uma directiva de formatação. Se ao processar o input a validação desta directiva falhar, o `scanf(...)` para de ler os inputs e retorna.

Uma directiva pode ser constituída pelo(s) seguinte(s) elementos:

- Uma sequência de espaços;
- Um carácter normal (a-zA-Z0-9, etc) desde que não seja um espaço branco ou um %;
- Um especificador de conversão que é iniciado pelo carácter %. Os inputs são lidos e convertidos segundo este especificador e colocados no ponteiro respectivo (por exemplo, `scanf("%d", &i)`.

No seu caso, a sua directiva de formatação é "Dia %d". Com esta directiva, o `scanf(...)` está a espera de ler um input que comece como "Dia " e depois um inteiro. Por isso quando coloca algo que não comece com "Dia " o `scanf(...)` falha e nada é lido para a variável `dia`.

Exemplos:

`scanf(...)` efectuado com sucesso:

```
int dia = 0;
scanf("Dia %d", &dia); // Input: Dia 123
printf("%d", dia); // Output: 123
```

`scanf(...)` falha:

```
int dia = 0;
scanf("Dia %d", &dia); // Input: 123
printf("%d", dia); // Output: 0 (valor colocado em dia)
```

`scanf(...)` falha (variável dia não foi inicializada):

```
int dia;
scanf("Dia %d", &dia); // Input: 123
printf("%d", dia); // Output: int_min (valor default de inicialização do int)
```

Para mais informações consulte esta [página](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) que descreve exaustivamente como funciona o `scanf(...)` e as strings de formatação suportadas.

Comment: Muito interessante. Obrigado amigo! me ajudou bastante também.