# O que são os conceitos: comportamento indefinido, não especificado e definido pela implementação?

Tags: c, c++, terminologia, característica-linguagem

Qual a diferença entre os três termos "comportamento indefinido", "comportamento não especificado" e "comportamento definido pela implementação"?

Por que eles existem nessas formas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As linguagens mais seguras tentam evitar esses comportamentos. Em linguagens onde espera-se o melhor da performance, flexibilidade e aproveitamento da arquitetura é mais comum deixar algumas coisas em aberto. É o caso de C e C++.

Primeiro entenda que essas coisas cabem em [especificação da linguagem. E a implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) pode ou não fazer diferente, justamente como um dos termos já indica.

## Comportamento indefinido

É uma situação em que a linguagem não determina o que deve ser feito, não diz que deve gerar erro, ou que deve executar em uma forma específica, não tem uma solução para isso. Espera-se que ele seja útil em algum cenário na forma usada e que o programador saiba das dificuldades existentes e evite nos demais cenários.

Então podemos dizer que é uma sintaxe válida sem que indique com clareza o que acontecerá ali.

Um exemplo bem conhecido é o acesso de uma informação que não é a desejada. Isso ocorre:

- quando lê um elemento de um vetor além dos seus limites
- tenta escrever além do limite do vetor, estrutura ou tipo escalar
- quando dereferencia um ponteiro nulo ou com valor que não era para ser um ponteiro
- acessa uma área da memória que continha a informação desejada por um tempo, mas o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) dela expirou.
- entre outras

Algumas expressões esquisitas podem gerar um comportamento indefinido. Um exemplo bem conhecido é o `i++ + ++i`. A sintaxe é ambígua. Claro que a linguagem poderia ter definido que isso é um erro e dizer como tratar um caso desse tipo ou ter uma regra para torná-la não ambígua, mas optaram por não fazer. Provavelmente sem querer no começo, e proposital depois para evitar quebra de compatibilidade com algum código existente que faça uso.

Há casos em que a especificação diz claramente que o comportamento é indefinido. Ela diz que não é para ter uma regra que regule-o. O que não impede de uma situação específica sempre ter o mesmo resultado. Depende do tipo de comportamento indefinido. O fato é que qualquer comportamento que tiver, está em acordo com a especificação da linguagem, ainda que provavelmente seja um erro fazer aquilo. **A ideia é que a implementação (compilador) deixe fazer errado mesmo**.

A especificação da linguagem C fala isso de forma clara. C++ possui definições parecidas:

> 3.4.3 1 **undefined behavior** behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
>
> 2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).
>
> 3 EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow.

## Comportamento não especificado

Aqui muda um pouco. A implementação precisa tratar a situação para gerar um comportamento definido, mas qual será ele é problema da implementação e só dela. Ela não precisa informar ninguém de como isso é feito. Não precisa sequer ser consistente entre versões.

Um exemplo típico:

```
void f(int n, int m);
int f1() {
    return 1;
}
int f2() {
    return 2;
}
f(f1(), f2());
```

Não está especificado qual das duas funções deve ser chamada antes. Cada compilador pode fazer como quiser, no momento que quiser, desde que faça algo válido.

> 3.4.4 1 unspecified behavior use of an unspecified value, or other behavior where this International Standard provides two or more possibilities and imposes no further requirements on which is chosen in any instance
>
> 2 EXAMPLE An example of unspecified behavior is the order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated.

## Comportamento definido pela implementação

Aqui chegamos em um ponto melhor. A especificação deixa a implementação fazer como quiser, mas isso deve ser oficialmente declarado (documentação) para o usuário (o programador) saber o que acontecerá. Espera-se que tenha alguma compatibilidade entre versões, ou pelo menos uma forma de escolher entre os comportamentos definidos se for necessário mudar.

Um exemplo:

```
int *o = malloc(0 * sizeof *o);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/UndefinedBehavior.c).

O seu compilador (biblioteca dele) deve documentar se retornará um nulo ou um ponteiro válido único para um local que nada será reservado.

> 3.4.1 1 implementation-defined behavior unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made
>
> 2 EXAMPLE An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right.

## Comportamento definido

Na verdade a maioria dos comportamentos são definidos pela especificação e para uma implementação conformar com a especificação precisa fazer exatamente o que ela manda. Ainda bem. Por ser o normal nem há uma definição dele.

Se seu código precisa ser portável, só os comportamentos definidos devem ser usados, ou as outras três formas de comportamentos precisam ser devidamente tratadas em cada ambiente de compilação de forma individual.

## Conclusão

Apesar de serem muito usados e importantes para C e C++, os termos podem ser usados em outras linguagens.