# Existe diferença entre usar "return" ou "exit()" para encerrar a função "main()"?

Tags: c, c++, funções, estilo-de-codificação, return

A função [`exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/exit) encerra a execução da aplicação imediatamente. O comando `return` faz sair da função, mas quando está dentro do `main()` ele também sairá da aplicação, inclusive o valor usado nele será devolvido para quem chamou a aplicação como um código de erro (zero é ok), assim como a função de saída.

Claro que há a diferença em outras funções, onde o `exit()` encerra aplicação imediatamente e o comando voltará o fluxo de execução para a função chamadora.

Se ambas fazem a mesma coisa na situação descrita, tanto faz usar um ou outro?

Comment: Não me parece correto dizer que a função "exit" encerra a aplicação "imediatamente". Este comentário se aplicaria melhor às funções "_exit" e "_Exit". Veja https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx, https://linux.die.net/man/3/exit e https://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit.

Comment: @JoséX. isso é um pergunta, certo? Perguntas pressupõem que não há total domínio da informação. A resposta explica isso de forma mais adequada. Eu posso colocar sobre essas outras funções na resposta, acha que ajuda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Há uma diferença semântica importante em C++. O `return` encerrará o escopo e chamará todos os destrutores pendentes. Se for o encerramento da aplicação mesmo, raramente a chamada dos destrutores produzirá um resultado diferente, mas tecnicamente é possível que algum deles faça algo que seja importante para o fim da aplicação, nem que seja imprimir uma informação relevante para o usuário ou *log*.

Mesmo que a ação pareça a mesma, a função `exit()` provoca uma saía prematura da aplicação. Então a execução é encerrada quase imediatamente. O `exit()` finaliza os objetos estáticos, mas não os destrutores. Já o [`abort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort)  e [`_Exit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/_Exit) nem isso faz e encerra na hora.

Há diferença mesmo em C se tiver funções registradas com [`atexit()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit). Essas funções sempre serão executadas não importa como a aplicação está sendo encerrada. Mas haverá [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) se uma das funções vinculadas em `atexit()` tiver referência para algum dado na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). Ocorre algo parecido com [`setbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf) e [`setvbuf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf). Isso é importante principalmente em C.<sup>[documentação](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.3p1)</sup>

Note que a função `main()` não é especial e pode ser chamada dentro da aplicação. Nesse caso haverá uma diferença importante já que um `return` não encerrará a aplicação, ainda que no contexto da pergunta isso não aconteceria. Mas entenda que se o que você escreveu não for chamado pelo sistema operacional (de uma forma ou de outra) e esse `main()` faz parte de um módulo que será carregado e usado em outra aplicação, o seu módulo encerrará a aplicação e não só o seu código se usar o `exit()`, o `return` então será o mais adequado na maioria das situações.

Uma chamada ao `main()` pode ser recursiva, ainda que não deva. Claro que há diferença nesse caso, mas cai no que eu falei no parágrafo anterior.

Por isso que sempre tem que **escolher o jeito mais semanticamente correto**. Se quer encerrar a aplicação imediatamente use o `exit()`, caso contrário use o `return`. Muitas pessoas dizem que se o `main()` está encerrando a aplicação, o `exit()` é o mais adequado. Nem todo mundo concorda, principalmente em C++. Por isso que é bom entender o funcionamento, as implicações de cada um e **não seguir regras cegamente**.

Não sei se conta como diferença, por ser uma função, para usá-la precisa usar um `#include` para ela estar disponível, e se a unidade de código que ela está contida não entraria na aplicação, o executável ficará um pouco maior. O comando está sempre disponível.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).