# Qual a diferença entre #include <filename> e #include “filename”?

Tags: c, c++, include

Por que usamos

```
#include <filename>
```

e

```
#include "filename"
```

Quando usar cada? Quais as diferenças?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <filename>
```

É usado para as bibliotecas padrões da linguagem. Em geral o compilador já sabe onde estão os cabeçalhos do que faz parte da linguagem. Obviamente isso pode ser configurado. Mas como será feito é [problema da implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101).

Claro que nada impede colocar outras coisas junto, mas não é recomendado.

Então

```
#include <filename.h>
```

provavelmente deve acessar `/usr/include/file.h` ou `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0\Include`

Em C++ geralmente não precisa usar o `.h`, pelo menos para os cabeçalhos específicos da linguagem e não os que são "importados" do C, embora tenha nomes sem o `.h` para acessar os cabeçalhos de C (ex.: `cstdio` no lugar de `stdio.h`).

Nota-se então que não é necessário que tenha um nome de arquivo existente, o nome escrito precisa definir qual é o cabeçalho, a forma como ele vai achar o que deve ser incluso depende do compilador, e é comum ter esses nomes que fazem um mapeamento para outros arquivos (ex.: `cstring` -> `string.h`).

```
#include "filename"
```

É usado para bibliotecas de terceiros e seu próprio código. Em geral ele olha na pasta do que está sendo compilado. Há diretivas no compilador para adicionar outros locais. A implementação exata também é dependente do compilador.

Se não for possível fazer esta busca, ele decai para a forma anterior. Se não achar algo haverá um erro.

Então

```
#include "file.h"
```

deve acessar `./file.h`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/IncludeHeader.c).

Em C++ algumas pessoas preferem usar `.hpp` para deixar claro que é compatível com C++ e não C.