# Usar import ou include em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, diretivas-de-compilação

```
#import <stdio.h>
```

ou

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Qual é a forma correta de se utilizar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não use `#import`, ele é fora de padrão, no máximo use `#pragma once` se deseja garantir que a inclusão ocorra apenas uma vez.

Veja:

- [Como funciona a diretiva Include?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre #include <filename> e #include “filename”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175093/101)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)