# O que significa a expressão "a+t" no segundo parâmetro de fopen em C?

Tags: c, arquivo, fopen

Estava me deparando com um código aqui e fiquei curiosa sobre esse trecho:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("Agenda.txt","a+t");
```

Pra que serve o `"a+t"`?

Comment: Olha, o "t" eu não manjo, porque não conheço muito `C`. Mas posso garantir que `a` significa: "sempre adicione o conteúdo a partir da última linha do arquivo"

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigada!!

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 8):

Isto é o modo de acesso ao arquivo que está sendo aberto. O "a+" indica que só pode adicionar dados ao final do arquivo (*append*) e que pode ser lido também ("+"). A gravação precisa sempre ser oficializada com [`fflush()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

["t" indica que só pode usar texto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160), mas isto não é padrão do C. Só algum compilador específico aceita em plataforma específica, mas isto é considera um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101).

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

Comment: Como o arquivo é aberto com `fopen()`, tem que ser efetivado usando `fflush()`.

Comment: @Wtrmute sim, acho que foi só typo, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o site da [fopen](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/fopen.htm).

"a+t" ou "at+" ele abre um arquivo de texto no modo leitura ou atualização (adicionando as novas informações no final do arquivo).

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigada!

Comment: O "modo texto" se refere à tradução de retornos de carro, que ele converte ao ler de `CR LF` para `LF`, e ao contrário ao escrever. A _flag_ oposta, `b`, explicitamente desabilita essa conversão.