# Por que a saída dá 16?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x, y = 3;
    x = (++y) + (++y) + (++y);
    std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::cout << "O valor de x é " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y = " << y;
    return 0;
}
```

Rodei esse código e a saída deu 16, porém pela lógica não seria 15, já que 4+5+6=15.

O compilador exibe 2 erros iguais na linha 7:

> "A operação em 'y' pode ser indefinida"

Comment: Apesar de já respondida, se ainda quiser que o resultado seja 15 : ) Faça:  x = (++y) + ((y++) + (y++));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É exatamente o que o compilador está dizendo, não há como ele garantir o que acontecerá com esta expressão que gera efeitos colaterais, não há nada na especificação que obrigue o código funcionar de uma determinada forma, isto é [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101). Não há uma ordem garantida de execução. Quando altera uma variável mais de uma vez na mesma expressão, entre outras operações,  fica complicado definir o resultado correto.

Essencialmente nunca use operadores de atribuição em operações complexas assim, a não ser que saiba muito bem o que está fazendo. Se fizer cada operação separada resulta em 15.

Isto é explicado em [mais detalhes na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Veja [como a versão atual do GCC gera o código](https://godbolt.org/g/m143aD) e note a mudança de ordem em relação ao que se espera.

Agora [veja como o Clang 5.0 gera](https://godbolt.org/g/GjrgPV) e note que ele age como se espera.

[Coloque no seu navegador](https://tbfleming.github.io/cib/) e veja como o Clang realmente gera o resultado correto de 15 (sim, você está rodando no seu navegador).