# Retorno de ponteiro que apontam para um vetor de caractere local?

Tags: c, ponteiro, return, char

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *local(void);

void main(void) {
    char *ponteiro = local();
    printf("%s\n", ponteiro); /*Saida = - (*/
}

char *local(void) {
    char nome[12] = "programador";
    char *ponteiro = nome;
    return ponteiro;
}
```

No exemplo acima tenho a seguinte saída comentada no código "- (" creio eu que seja algum lixo na região da memoria, porem se eu acesso o ponteiro por meio de índice ele me imprime o caractere, por exemplo `ponteiro[0]` imprimirá "p", agora se eu uso o modificador de tipo de classe de armazenamento `static` na variável `nome` a saída ocorre como esperado.

Por que ocorre isso nas três ocasiões citadas?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1):

Vamos entender oque está fazendo cada linha:

```
char nome[12] = "programador";
```

Criou um espaço na [pilha de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) para um ponteiro para caracteres que ficarão alocados em uma área estática da aplicação. Lá são 12 caracteres (11 úteis por causa do terminador). Este ponteiro é chamado de `nome`.

```
char *ponteiro = nome;
```

Criou um espaço na pilha de dados para um ponteiro (4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura) e colocou o ponteiro para o espaço anterior referenciado como `nome`.

```
return ponteiro;
```

Encerrou a execução da função retornando (copiando) o valor desse ponteiro, "destruindo" toda área alocada nesse função (na verdade é só indisponibilizado)

Agora voltamos para a função principal. `ponteiro` aqui tem o mesmo valor de `ponteiro da função chamada, houve uma cópia.

```
printf("%s\n", ponteiro); /*Saida = - (*/
```

O ponteiro aí está apontando e portando acessando a área de memória que foi destruída. Qualquer coisa pode acontecer. Isto chama-se [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101).

Quando você coloca um `static` na variável está dizendo que deseja alocar o conteúdo na área estática da sua aplicação, uma área que nunca é destruída (e diferente do *stack*), então o dado está lá como deseja.

Este código demonstra melhor o que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *local(void) {
    static char nomex[12] = "aaaaaaaaaa";
    char nome[12] = "programador";
    char *ponteiro = nome;
    printf("%s\n", nome);
    printf("%s\n", ponteiro);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ponteiro);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)nome);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)nomex); 
    printf("%p\n", (void *)&ponteiro); 
    return ponteiro;
}

int main(void) {
    char *ponteiro = local();
    printf("%s\n", ponteiro);
    printf("%c\n", ponteiro[0]);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ponteiro);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gp80y1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/thxnnagl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Examples.c).

Agora veja este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *local(void) {
    static char nomex[12] = "aaaaaaaaaa";
    char nome[12] = "programador";
    char *ponteiro = nome;
    return ponteiro;
}

int main(void) {
    char *ponteiro = local();
    printf("%s\n", ponteiro);
    printf("%c\n", ponteiro[0]);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ponteiro);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/78pl8o). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lahkohyw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Examples2.c).

Dependendo do compilador dará resultados diferentes, mesmo não mudando nada nas variáveis.

Comment: Bom foi uma ótima explicação mas fiquei com uma dúvida a matriz char nome pode ser visto como um unico ponteiro que aponta , pelo que entendi para pilha de dados ou e só um identificador que armazena x endereços de memória onde cada indice x aponta para uma região da memoria?

Comment: É o primeiro, `nome` aponta para o primeiro caractere na pilha, os demais são acessados por aritmética `nome + posicao`

Comment: Muito bom!!! então uma "string" e inteiro é uma constante alocada em uma área estática? e quando faço uma atribuição estou movendo da área estática para uma área dinâmica? já que matriz é alocada na pilha e uma pilha e uma região dinâmica e mutável correto?

Comment: Um literal sim. Uma *string*  geralmente fica em uma área específica de dados, o inteiro já fica na área de código mesmo (a não ser que seja uma sequência de inteiros), mas as duas áreas são estáticas. A primeira atribuição de algo que vem de um literal é mover do estático para o automático (o termo correto da pilha). Uma matriz pode ser alocada na pilha, ou no monte (*heap*) que é dinâmica. Estas regiões são mutáveis. Pesquise o termos aqui no site, já tem perguntas sobre.