# Resultado de teste de mesa não é igual ao compilado?

Tags: php, c, operadores

O código abaixo quando executado retorna o resultado para `m = 0`, mas fazendo o teste de mesa o resultado deveria ser `-2`.

Não consigo provar o `0`como resultado a não ser que a variável `t++` quando em `(t * t++)`, somente neste instante e somente ela, adquirisse o valor 4, que é algo também estranho. Testei em PHP e C.

```
 int t = 3;
 int p = -5;
 int q = 1;
 int m = (q * p + (t * t++)- (t + q))-2;
```

Comment: Você vai se "divertir" mais ainda quando começar a debugar e perceber que em `($t * $t++)` o "quatro" que voce disse é o... da esquerda..! e o três o da direita :D     (por essa mesma razão, em PHP normalmente é mais interessante usar `++$i` do que `$i++` em um laço `for`, sempre que possível, para evitar criação de uma referência desnecessária)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Não tentei debugar Bacco, mas o farei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviamente seu teste de mesa está errado. testes de mesa precisam simular o que o que computador faz e não o que você quer que ele faça. Nem sei se é o caso de teste de mesa, é só fazer o cálculo matemático simples.

Talvez esteja falando do [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) em C que é trocar o valor de `t` em andamento na expressão. Tire o `++` e dará o resultado que espera. Se precisa dele precisa ver onde quer chegar e montar a expressão de uma outra forma. Nunca use um operador que causa efeito colateral na variável no meio de uma expressão.

Em PHP pode ser diferente, em outra versão de compilador C ou outra plataforma pode ser diferente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int t = 3;
    int p = -5;
    int q = 1;
    int m = (q * p + (t * t) - (t + q)) - 2; 
    int n = (q * p + (t * ++t) - (t + q)) - 2;    
    t = 3;
    int o = (q * p + (t * t++) - (t + q)) - 2;    
    printf("%d, %d, %d", m, n, o);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/usH9ZD). E não funcionando [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/akeobyoa-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/IncrementBehavior.c).

Comment: Ola Maniero, obrigado por partilhar seu conhecimento, coloquei o mesmo código em Java que atribuiu -3 a "m". Acredito que todas as linguagem deveriam fazer o mesmo valor de atribuição. E é interessante o termo que usou "efeito colateral", pelo visto pode ser perigoso a forma de utilizar este operador de incremento.

Comment: Sim e sim. :) ...