# Chamar função recursiva com operador de decremento

Tags: c++, operadores

Escrevi um código para a resolução de um problema sobre soma de fatoriais. Quando criei a função recursiva para o cálculo do fatorial, utilizei na chamada da função o operador de decremento `--` seguido do número, e isso gerou um erro na resposta. Qual o motivo do uso do operador alterar a resposta? Segue abaixo o código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

long long int factorial(long long int num){
    if(num == 1 || num == 0) return 1;
    return num*factorial(--num);
}

int main() {
    long long int M, N;
    while(scanf("%lli %lli", &M, &N)!=EOF)
        cout << factorial(M)+factorial(N) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Pra que usar este operador ali? O que espera obter com isto? Ele vai decrementar um variável que não será usada depois, então não faz sentido fazer isto, só está tornando o código ineficiente e com potencial problema já que isto é considerado [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101). Este operador tem o efeito colateral de mudar o estado da variável, quando ela ocorre em um momento que a variável está sendo usada na mesma expressão não se sabe a ordem que será executada cada operação e tudo pode acontecer. O que deseja é só pegar o **valor** da variável e subtrair 1 antes de passar como argumento para a função, não quer mudar o valor dessa variável, então esse operador não faz sentido (se precisasse teria que fazer esta operação em outra linha).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

long long int factorial(long long int num) {
    if (num == 1 || num == 0) return 1;
    return num * factorial(num - 1);
}

int main() {
    long long int M, N;
    while (scanf("%lli %lli", &M, &N) != EOF) cout << factorial(M) + factorial(N) << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UYMeSJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Factorial). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Math/Factorial.cpp).