# Tamanho do tipo int com os prefixos short e long em C

Tags: c, variáveis

Minha arquitetura é Unix, logo por padrão o tamanho do tipo int é de 4 bytes, até ai tudo bem. No livro do Luis Dama ele afirma que os prefixos short e long resolvem o problema para portabilidade de programas entre arquiteturas diferentes, pois os prefixo short estabelece um valor mínimo de 2 bytes e o prefixo long um valor máximo de 4 bytes. Segundo ele uma declaração, numa arquitetura Unix, do tipo:

```
long int num;

printf("%d", sizeof(num));
```

Teria como saída:

```
4
```

Mas na prática a saída é:

```
8
```

Gostaria de saber se há um erro na informação repassada no livro(pag 31 da 10ª edição), ou se houve alguma mudança do padrão do C que não torna isso mais possível.

Comment: Alguns links úteis: http://linguagemc.com.br/tipos-de-dados-em-c/ e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844586/can-i-assume-the-size-of-long-int-is-always-4-bytes

Comment: Aqui está um exemplo do mundo real. Para o seguinte código: `#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("sizeof(long) = %zu\n", sizeof(long));
    return 0;
}`
Output on Debian 7 i686:
`sizeof(long) = 4`
Output on CentOS 7 x64:
`sizeof(long) = 8`

Comment: Pelo visto o autor comentou um erro ao afirmar que os prefixos definem um tamanho unico para qualquer arquitetura.

Comment: Você tem link do livro? Eu quero ler este livro,para me ver o trecho melhor.

Comment: http://www.ams.eti.br/livros/Luis_Damas.pdf  pag 42 do pdf

Comment: Ele errou feio.... Não sei de nada C,mas sabia disso. Os valores na memória são 8(long) bytes e 4(short) bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para portabilidade [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/149882) já fala um pouco sobre, onde o @Maniero [responde](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173887/149882):

> **Comportamento definido** 
>   Na verdade a maioria dos comportamentos são definidos pela especificação e para uma implementação conformar com a
>   especificação precisa fazer exatamente o que ela manda. Ainda bem. Por
>   ser o normal nem há uma definição dele.
>
> Se seu código precisa ser portável, só os comportamentos definidos
>   devem ser usados, ou as outras três formas de comportamentos precisam
>   ser devidamente tratadas em cada ambiente de compilação de forma
>   individual.

Segundo as respostas [nessa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35844586/11452150), não há garantias da especificação, nem POSIX, de tamanho ocupado em memória que uma variável dos tipos `short`, `int` e `long` terão. Em contrapartida no [rascunho da especificação](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) tem-se as garantias de *"valores mínimos"*:

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in
>   magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.

Por exemplo, no meu sistema:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main(void){
    printf("The value of INT_MAX is: %d.\n", INT_MAX);
    printf("The value of INT_MIN is: %d.\n", INT_MIN);
}
```

Cujo resultado é:

```
mateus@debian:~/desk$ ./a.out 
The value of INT_MAX is: 2147483647.
The value of INT_MIN is: -2147483648.
```

Note que o valor do `INT_MIN` no meu sistema ***é menor*** do que o da especificação, mas em valores absolutos o da minha máquina é maior, e portanto neste caso atende à especificação.

Ainda no rascunho §5.2.4.2.1:

> minimum value for an object of type **short int** 
>   SHRT_MIN -32767 // −(2^15 − 1)
>
> maximum value for an object of type **short int** 
>   SHRT_MAX +32767 // 2^15 − 1
>
> minimum value for an object of type **int** 
>   INT_MIN -32767 // −(2^15 − 1)
>
> maximum value for an object of type **int** 
>   INT_MAX +32767 // 2^15 − 1
>
> minimum value for an object of type **long int** 
>   LONG_MIN -2147483647 // −(2^31 − 1)
>
> maximum value for an object of type **long int** 
>   LONG_MAX +2147483647 // 2^31 − 1

O que escrevi é sobre C11, o livro é anterior, embora eu não possa garantir que ele atendia aos padrões mais antigos da linguagem, porque eu mesmo não conheço.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Aqui está um exemplo do mundo real. 
Para o seguinte código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  printf("sizeof(long) = %zu\n", sizeof(long)); 
  return 0;
}
```

## Output on Debian 7 i686: sizeof(long) = 4

## Output on CentOS 7 x64: sizeof(long) = 8

Luis Dama afirmou no seu livro:

`short = 2 bytes
long = 4 bytes`

Seu livro: http://www.ams.eti.br/livros/Luis_Damas.pdf

Mas no outputs o valor é diferentes.

O valor retornar nesse diferente:

```c
sizeof(short): %d\n", 4
sizeof(int): %d\n", 4
sizeof(long): %d\n", 4
sizeof(long long): 8
sizeof(size_t): 4
sizeof(void *): 4
Hit enter to exit.
```

Veja um exemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109984/c-c-sizeofshort-sizeofint-sizeoflong-sizeoflong-long-etc-on-a

Será que ele errou ou teve falta de atenção?

Fonte: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844586/can-i-assume-the-size-of-long-int-is-always-4-bytes