# Erro bizarro com alocação dinâmica

Tags: c, string, memória, alocação

Escrevi esse simples programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char *nome;

  nome = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
  if(nome == NULL) {
    puts("Erro de alocacao!");
    exit(1);
  }

  scanf(" %s", nome);

  nome = (char *)realloc(nome, strlen(nome));
  if(nome == NULL) {
    puts("Erro de realocacao!");
    exit(2);
  }

  printf("%s\n", nome);

  free(nome);

  return 0;
}
```

Aparentemente não possui nenhum erro, não é? Mas a verdade é que dependendo do meu *input*, ocorre um erro de execução chamado:

> corrupted size vs. prev_size Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Acabei de fazer os testes aqui e sizeof(char) retorna 1, ou seja, 1 byte e não 4 bytes.

Comment: Estou usando o gcc, não o g++.

Comment: Os comentários acima estão completamente equivocados. A especificação do C e do C++ é clara que o tamanho do tipo `char` é sempre 1 por isso não faz sentido usar `sizeof(char)`, assim como é ruim, e até errado fazer *cast* em `malloc()`. `gcc` e `g++` não são o mesmo compilador.

Comment: Sim também achei estranho as respostas do amigo, já li em vários lugares sobre o gcc e g++, e ninguém falou sobre os dois serem a mesma coisa. Falando de malloc(), também já li vários códigos em que é feito o casting, mas quando eu não faço o compilador não emite nenhum warning, então creio que sem casting também é correto.

Comment: É correto sem o *casting*, funcionar é diferente de estar certo, por isso que eu disse que não é assim que se aprende, vai aprender muita coisa errada só porque funciona. Em certas linguagens isso pode nem ser um problema tão grande, em C acreditar que funcionar é o mesmo que estar certo é um um enorme problema, por isso eu reafirmo  que não pode aprender na base da tentativa e erro.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

Claramente tem erro aí.

Você está alocando 10 bytes. Depois permite alguém entrar dados livremente, ou seja, alguém pode digitar algo maior que 10 bytes sem nenhuma restrição, o que já vai corromper a memória e em geral não haverá reclamação dor parte o compilador ou *runtime* (é possível ligar certas opções que pegam esse tipo de problema), depois por alguma razão que eu não faço ideia pega esse dado que já está fazendo algo errado e tenta mudá-lo de lugar para obter vantagem alguma. Ou seja, este código é bizarro.

Este erro em específico ocorre porque o `realloc()` precisa da informação do tamanho alocado para saber o que fazer, em alguns casos ele consegue identificar que esse dado está inválido e te mostra isso.

C é assim, se acha que estes comportamentos são bizarros (eles não são porque eles são documentados) então C não é uma linguagem para você, procure uma que faça gerenciamento de memória automático e não permite este tipo de comportamento (a custa de performance e flexibilidade).

Comment: Trocar de linguagem não é uma opção, adoro aprender sobre a linguagem C. Não é só por causa de um erro que vou abandonar todo o sistema! São com os erros que se aprende. Mas uma coisa que achei estranha, foi que esse código é basicamente uma adaptação do livro que estou usando para aprender a linguagem, chama-se Linguagem C do Luis Damas.

Comment: Como que você escreveria um código para realocar o tamanho de uma string?

Comment: Então comece aprender C, do jeito que está fazendo está se iludindo que está aprendendo. É com estudo que se aprende, na tentativa  e erro não se aprende, especialmente C. Se o livro manda fazer isso jogue o livro fora. Pelo estilo de código que está usando percebi que está aprendendo várias coisas erradas, pode ser culpa do livro (mas não posso afirmar).

Comment: Acredito que seja do livro, pq eu estudo com muita atenção, sempre releio várias vezes, mesmo entendendo o conteúdo. Quais livros vc me recomenda para aprender C da melhor forma possível?

Comment: Eu não recomendo porque cada um tem sua realidade, pode ter problemas que eu não sei, o que eu confio não é muito adequado para a maioria das pessoas, algumas pessoas recomendaram alguns em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info. A melhor forma de aprender C é ter a atitude correta, mais que ler um livro.

Comment: O livro do Luis Damas possui alguns erros. Eu mesmo já fiz uma pergunda aqui porque achei que a explicação dele não estava correta. Pior que a explicação realmente estava errada. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398659/tamanho-do-tipo-int-com-os-prefixos-short-e-long-em-c<a>