# Como testar se a função free(); funcionou corretamente?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória

Estou criando o tipo abstrato de dado Matriz 2D, e uma das funções que estou fazendo na TAD é essa:

```
int mat2D_free(TMat2D *mat)
{
    free(mat->data);
    free(mat);
}
```

Isto é, uma função para destruir a matriz.
Minha intenção é que essa função retorne `0` caso tenha feito o `free();` com sucesso e `-1`, caso haja falha.

Qual seria o teste adequado para saber se o `free();` de fato liberou a memória?

O ponteiro no qual foi usado o `free();` muda de alguma forma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não tem como. `free()` não retorna valor, portanto não tem como reportar sucesso ou fracasso.

Na verdade, você só pode chamar `free()` com um ponteiro válido, alocado por `malloc()` e companhia; ou então com `NULL`, caso em que ele não faz nada. Chamar com um ponteiro inválido vai causar corrupção do heap. Alguns sistemas conseguem detectar alguns casos de ponteiro inválido ou duplo `free()`, terminando o programa imediatamente com uma mensagem, mas nem com isso é possível contar. Em geral a implementação de `free()` é feita para ser extremamente rápida, e vai manipular os dados apontados pelo ponteiro assumindo que estão ok.

Se precisar testar o programa para ver se não está ocorrendo corrupção, pode tentar ferramentas como Valgrind, mas isso é para debugging e verificação, não é algo para produção.

Answer (score 5):

Se você está falando de verificar se a função fez seu papel corretamente então não precisa verificar nada, ela sempre fez, não tem como ela falhar a não ser por uma situação catastrófica na máquina, o que faz sua aplicação, e quem sabe algo mais, ficar inviável, e o menor dos seus problemas é se o `free()` funcionou. Ou pode não ter feito o que espera porque chamou ela de forma errada, por exemplo ter passado algo que não é um ponteiro ou é um ponteiro errado.

Se está falando sobre determinar se você programador usou certo a função, não tem jeito, você tem que analisar o código profundamente, ou testar todas possibilidades, o que pode ser muitas, para achar isso, não tem como a própria função fazer.

E se está falando se está liberando certo uma alocação, então sua única chance além da verificação manual é usar alguma ferramenta que acompanha todas as alocações e mostra quando há alguma anormalidade. Não é 100% seguro mas ajuda muito. Uma dela é o [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) ou [DrMemory](https://github.com/dynamorio/drmemory) ou [Insure++](https://www.parasoft.com/products/insure).

Se você tentar usar o valor da variável que foi liberada terá um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) porque ela não terá mais um valor válido. A variável que definiu o ponteiro deixa de ter um valor válido, então não pode mais acessar. O valor permanece o mesmo. Em C o programador tem que tomar conta disto e não tentar fazer o acesso ao que era válido logo antes, não tem facilidade na linguagem ou biblioteca.