# Ponteiro apontando para outro ponteiro, como usar o free() corretamente?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, malloc

Quando tenho um ponteiro apontando para outro ponteiro como:

```
int *ponteiro1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *ponteiro2;

*ponteiro1 = 5;

ponteiro2 = ponteiro1;
free(ponteiro2);
```

E utilizo o comando `free(ponteiro2)`, então estou desalocando o `ponteiro1`? Se sim, devo depois fazer algum tratamento para o `ponteiro2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos olhar o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *ponteiro1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ponteiro1 = 5;
    int *ponteiro2 = ponteiro1;
    printf("%p == %p, %d == %d\n", (void *)ponteiro1, (void *)ponteiro2, *ponteiro1, *ponteiro2);
    free(ponteiro2);
    printf("%p == %p, %d == %d", (void *)ponteiro1, (void *)ponteiro2, *ponteiro1, *ponteiro2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jTY1GB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ntdikucw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/FreeAddress.c).

Aí mostra que as duas variáveis tem o mesmo valor, e esse valor é o ponteiro. Também vemos, obviamente, que o valor contido na memória alocada é o mesmo quando derreferenciamos o ponteiro e acessamos o objeto apontado, afinal se é o mesmo endereço nas variáveis então apontamos certamente para o mesmo objeto. Nem poderia ser diferente, em lugar algum o código criou 2 objetos.

Se você considerar que `free()` libera um endereço da memória quando ele é liberado nada mais naquele ponto deve ser usado. Da mesma forma que você alocou só uma vez deve liberar só uma vez. Não existem duas alocações. A atribuição de uma variável na outra não está criando uma nova alocação. Em C você tem que ser explícito em tudo.

Inclusive se você tentar liberar de novo terá um [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101).

É importante notar que o valor da variável não é zerado, você não deveria tentar acessar esse endereço depois de um `free()`.

Algumas pessoas gostam de zerar o valor da variável para evitar um acesso indevido não percebido. Se você zerar e tentar acessar depois provavelmente quebrará a aplicação que é melhor que funcionar por coincidência e em outro momento dar resultado errado sem aviso.

Se não ficou claro, o valor da variável que é do tipo ponteiro nunca é o valor do objeto, existem dois valores completamente distintos na memória, esse tipo provoca sempre uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para acessar o real objeto.

## Zerando valor do objeto

O que eu achei curioso é que após o `free()` o valor do objeto alocado nesse endereço foi considerado 0. Dá a impressão que a função `free()` zera o valor, mas isso não é para acontecer. É claro que o compilador é livre para fazer o que quiser, mas teria custo e C incentiva não colocar custos ocultos que podem não ser necessários. Em geral a simples liberação ainda permitirá o acesso ao valor do objeto se nada sobrescrevê-lo.

Pesquisando um pouco parece que há caso que a liberação da memória da aplicação pode liberar a memória para o sistema operacional. Isso ocorrendo o endereço não é liberado para acessar pela aplicação. Curiosamente não dá erro e só acessa um valor neutro. Fiquei de cabelo em pé porque provavelmente gera algum custo. Não quer dizer que seja isso, pode ser que haja mudança no valor mesmo, teria que pesquisar no compilador ou biblioteca dele para identificar o que ele faz.

Pode ser que acontece só em modo *debug*, o que eu não gosto da ideia porque muda a semântica do código, pode até ocultar um *bug*. Faria mais sentido porque nesse modo a performance não é problema, mas parece uma solução ruim.

Olhando [o fonte](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c) da alocação pode ter ocorrido um meio termo:

```
struct malloc_chunk {

  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

  /* Only used for large blocks: pointer to next larger size.  */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};
```

Um bloco de alocação pode ter sobrescrito nessa situação o valor do objeto. Isso não quer dizer que ocorrerá sempre, mas aconteceu um caso que não liberar para o sistema operacional, mas teve um processamento de gerenciamento de memória interno que usou a memória dentro do `free()`.

Aí eu fico pensando que até mesmo o `printf()` poderia, em tese, ter feito alguma coisa que sobrescreveu o valor enquanto ele estava processando a impressão. Não acho bom e acredito ser menos provável. Não lembro dessa função fazer uma alocação no *heap*.

Answer (score 2):

Ao fazer `ponteiro2 = ponteiro1`, `ponteiro2` não está  a apontar para `ponteiro1`, mas sim estão a compartilhar o mesmo endereço de memória já que você está a atribuir a ele o valor de `ponteiro1` que é esse endereço de memória.

Portanto o valor de `*ponteiro2` também é o mesmo `5` que você atribuiu à esse endereço de memória ao fazer `*ponteiro1 = 5`.

Ao fazer `free (ponteiro2)`, você está a liberar o endereço de memória compartilhado pelos dois ponteiros. Neste momento, tanto `ponteiro1` quanto `ponteiro2` estão a apontar pra um endereço que não está mais reservado pra eles.

Agora ao tentar aceder à `*ponteiro1` ou `*ponteiro2`, ocorrerá o erro de `Segmentation fault` - "erro que ocorre quando um programa tenta aceder (para leitura ou escrita) um endereço na memória RAM que está reservado para outro programa (ou o próprio sistema operativo) ou que não existe."

Resposta: Já não precisa fazer nada ao `ponteiro1` nem ao `ponteiro2`, a menos que queira fazer `ponteiro1 = NULL` e `ponteiro2 = NULL` se quiser voltar a utilizar as variáveis mais tarde.

Comment: Mais sobre `segmentation fault`: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falha_de_segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 1):

> Quando tenho um ponteiro apontando para outro ponteiro como:

```
int* ponteiro1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
int* ponteiro2;

*ponteiro1 = 5;

ponteiro2 = ponteiro1;
free(ponteiro2);
```

Você **não** tem um ponteiro apontando para outro ponteiro. `ponteiro1` é `int*`, `ponteiro2` é `int*` e você apenas fez os dois apontarem para o **mesmo lugar**.

#### isso seria "apontar para outro ponteiro":

```
int   valor = 42;
int*  p2    = &valor;
int** p3    = &p2;
printf(
    "Valor: %d ponteiro2 aponta para %d. int** p3 "
    "aponta para %d\n",
    valor, *p2, **p3);
```

E aqui `p3` aponta para um `int*`. Esse trecho mostra

```
Valor: 42 ponteiro2 aponta para 42. int** p3 aponta para 42
```

> E utilizo o comando free(ponteiro2), então estou desalocando o ponteiro1? Se sim, devo depois fazer algum tratamento para o ponteiro2

Não, não está. Não desaloca ponteiros, desaloca áreas de memória que se supõe previamente alocadas por uma chamada a `malloc()` ou `calloc()`
O "tratamento" que deve se acostumar a fazer é invalidar os dois ponteiros imediatamente. Ponteiros perdidos são uma das maiores causas de erro em C. Vou deixar um exemplo ao final.

#### sobre o código como postado

Nem todo programa vai ter 5 ou 25 linhas. Logo vão ter 2.500. Evite a todo custo deixar um ponteiro inválido ou em estado desconhecido. ao invés de

```
int* ponteiro1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
int* ponteiro2;

*ponteiro1 = 5;

ponteiro2 = ponteiro1;
free(ponteiro2);
```

prefira sempre

```
int* ponteiro1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ponteiro1     = 5;

int* ponteiro2 = ponteiro1;

printf(
    "\
Valor apontado por ponteiro1: %d\n\
Valor apontado por ponteiro2: %d\n\
    ",
    *ponteiro1, *ponteiro2);

free(ponteiro2);
ponteiro2 = ponteiro1 = NULL;
```

Que mostra

```
Valor apontado por ponteiro1: 5
Valor apontado por ponteiro2: 5
```

Assim iniciaiza `ponteiro2` já na declaração e na linha seguinte ao `free()` invalida os dois ponteiros.

#### Exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int* ponteiro1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ponteiro1     = 5;

    int* ponteiro2 = ponteiro1;

    printf(
        "\
    Valor apontado por ponteiro1: %d\n\
    Valor apontado por ponteiro2: %d\n\
",
        *ponteiro1, *ponteiro2);

    free(ponteiro2);
    ponteiro2 = ponteiro1 = NULL;

    int   valor = 42;
    int*  p2    = &valor;
    int** p3    = &p2;
    printf(
        "Valor: %d ponteiro2 aponta para %d. int** p3 "
        "aponta para %d\n",
        valor, *p2, **p3);
    return 0;
}
```

que mostra

```
Valor apontado por ponteiro1: 5
Valor apontado por ponteiro2: 5
Valor: 42 ponteiro2 aponta para 42. int** p3 aponta para 42
```