# Valor de um "for" retornado infinitamente

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, for

Contextualizando: Tenho um exercício que sugere a criação de um programa para ler notas de alunos e mostrar as notas iguais ou maiores que a média.

Dessa forma, o seguinte código foi escrito:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    float media;
    float alunos[5];
    int posicao;
    float soma=0;
    
    for(posicao=0;posicao<5;posicao=posicao++)
    {
        scanf("%f", &alunos[posicao]);
        soma=soma+alunos[posicao];
    }
    media=soma/5;
    for(posicao=0;posicao<5;posicao++)
    {
        if(alunos[posicao] >= media)
        printf("%.2f \n", alunos[posicao]);
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Primeira dúvida: Por que quando o terceiro parâmetro da estrutura de repetição é igual `posicao++` ela ultrapassa o limite que deveria ser 5?

Trocando o valor que gerou a primeira dúvida por outro equivalente `posicao=posicao+1`, sigo na construção do código.

Segunda dúvida: Por que as notas maiores ou iguais à média não são retornadas? Se for digitado por exemplo, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, a soma seria 15 e a média 3, portanto, os números 3, 4 e 5 deveriam ser exibidos, mas não são.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira dúvida é que gera [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101), o compilador pode fazer o que quiser com aquela atribuição em cima de algo que já é uma atribuição (no caso ela está atribuindo antes de fazer o incremento). Oi faz a atribuição "manual" ou deixa a "automática" do incremento acontecer, não faça as duas.

Só é estranho fazer certo em um lugar e errado no outro, faça igual ao que estava certo.

Não consegui reproduzir o segundo problema, eu só reorganizei o código e tirei o erro da primeira dúvida e funcionou, como era esperado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    float alunos[5];
    float soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf("%f", &alunos[i]);
        soma += alunos[i];
    }
    float media = soma / 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) if (alunos[i] >= media) printf("%.2f\n", alunos[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/PpcSkx). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/qutricuk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/Increment.c).

Comment: Há, sim! Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda mano!

Answer (score 0):

posicao++ é um pós-incremento logo, em posicao=posicao++, posicao está recebendo ele mesmo e só depois sendo incrementado.
Se fosse um pré-incremento (posicao=++posicao), posicao seria incrementada.
Se a intenção for apenas incrementar em 1, basta usar posicao++ ou ++posicao, dispensando a atribuição.

Answer (score 0):

Para código C++ sugiro que você substitua

```
    scanf("%f", &alunos[posicao]);
```

por
cin >> alunos[posicao];

e
printf("%.2f\n", alunos[i]);
por
cout << alunos[i] << endl;

Evite usar recursos C ou depreciados pra evitar conflito com compiladores mais modernos