# Como imprimir o endereço de uma função C++ com o cout?

Tags: c++, funções, ponteiro

Eu estava assistindo um tutorial de pointers o qual foi escrito isto:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getNumber()
{
    return 5;
}

int main()
{
    cout << getNumber;
}
```

O output do vídeo foi o endereço da função, mas quando eu escrevo o mesmo código, o meu output é `1`. Eu sei que é possível acessar o endereço com o `printf("%p", função);`, mas eu gostaria de entender por que os mesmos códigos tem um output diferente. A IDE do tutorial é o VS, a minha é o Quincy 2005.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Em *C* é fácil fazer isto, mas em *C++* o endereço da função é algo muito mais complexo e não tem como imprimir de forma direta, até porque ele pode mudar. E por causa disto a linguagem deixou isto livre para o compilador fazer como achar melhor, portanto difere e tem que ler a documentação do compilador para saber o que fazer. Veja mais em [O que são os conceitos: comportamento indefinido, não especificado e definido pela implementação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101).

[No SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11111969/221800) tem algumas implementações, mas tenho minhas dúvidas se funcionam em todos casos, talvez uma delas funcione. O que funciona só em alguns casos está errado.

[O IDE nada tem a ver com isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).