# Como se define as vulnerabilidades de uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, software

Essa pergunta pode parecer um pouco genérica e abrangente, mas acho necessária. Li em um artigo sobre as muitas vulnerabilidades da linguagem **C**, porém não entendi o que torna a linguagem em si vulnerável.

- São as estruturas de dados que ela suporta ou não suporta?
- Essas vulnerabilidades estão relacionadas com o tipo de aplicação?
- Existe alguma métrica para isso?

Answer (score 6):

É a existência de certas características. Ela é muito liberal em várias coisas e exige que o programador faça tudo certo. Não é que ela seja vulnerável, ela só exige que a pessoa saiba bem o que está fazendo, ela não te protege muito. E as linguagens são todas suscetíveis a algumas falhas. Não caia no marketing de alguma linguagem ser uma maravilha.

C faz você controlar toda memória na mão, e isso não é fácil, se você falhar em algum caso, dará problema.

C permite acessar a memória indiscriminadamente, e até onde não devia, é o programador que deve cuidar para que isso aconteça só do jeito certo.

C tem muito [comportamento indefinido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101) e o programador tem que saber bem disso e cuidar para que aconteça o que ele espera em cada plataforma.

C tem algumas funções da biblioteca padrão que são consideradas inseguras, então deve não usá-las ou usar com mais cuidado.

Tudo isso dá vantagens para C que outras linguagens não costumam ter.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda assim tenho dúvidas. Por exemplo, quando você diz de características que tornam a linguagem insegura, quais seriam elas ? E quais falhas são mais suscetíveis  em cada linguagem ? Sei que isso parece meio abrangente e talvez não tenha uma única resposta para ela, mas o que eu mais gostaria de saber qual é o fator determinante pra escolher uma linguagem de programação em determinado projeto.

Comment: A respeito das bibliotecas inseguras, imagino que você esteja falando das bibliotecas de alocação dinâmica de memória, correto ? Em todo lugar que eu vejo sempre tem algum aviso sobre isso, parece até "magia negra".